# jQuery Dynamic on form load

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to automatically do some form preprocessing whenever a form gets loaded on my website. This can happen via a normal page load, but also via an AJAX inline page load. So putting it in `$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });` does not suit my needs.

What I have so far:

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).ready(function() {
        $(this).find(".input input").each(function() {
            var required = $(this).data("required");
            var checkField = $(this).closest("tr").children(".check");
            var errorField = $(this).closest("tr").children(".errormessage");
            if (required) {
                $(checkField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
                $(checkField).html("&#x2718;");
                $(errorField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
                $(errorField).html("(Required)");
            }
            else {
                $(checkField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
                $(checkField).html("&#x2714;");
                $(errorField).css("color", "#000000");
                $(errorField).html("");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When putting it in `$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });` it works, but only for the first load. When I'm putting it outside that function, then it never works, it does not even reach the `$("form").each(function() { /* ... */ });`.

How to fix this?

Comment: That's because the `form` is loaded is loaded by Ajax, should you'd have to listen for the document for it, e.g. `$(document).find('form')`.. so it can be found after an `.ajax` load.

Comment: Shouldn't `$(document.ready(function() { $(document).on("ready", "form", function() { /* ... */ });` work? Or at least the idea behind it.

Comment: Just confirmed that it works with `.on("click", ...)`, however it does not seem to work with `"ready"`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a plugin out of this?  For example:

```
 $.fn.formRendering = function(){

     //process your code here
 };

 $('form').formRendering();
```